# DAO 3.6 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: vb6, windows-server-2008, dao

For historical reasons,we have some legacy vb6 server side code running on two identical Windows 2008 server boxes that uses dao 3.6 to get to the back end MS access databases. This has worked fine for years, and we are currently in the process of migrating all the code. However, one of the servers the code is running on is getting flakey, so we need to move the code to a new server as the migrated solution will not be ready for a while. 
The server that works ok is running Windwos Server Web 2008 Sp1 64 bit. The new server is Windows Server Standard 2008 R2 Standard Sp1.
In running tests on this new server, we started getting random freezing in the application. There is a simple loop that runs a select query on every table in the database.After adding a bunch of logging, it was freezing on a call to the OpenRecordset method of the DAO.Database object. Sometimes it would freeze for a few seconds, other times up to 10 - 11 minutes and then carry on. The queries being run are of this format, and should all return 0 records :

```
SELECT * FROM BlahBlah WHERE WriteTime > #25 Oct 2012 10:09:43#
```

When run directly on the database (i.e. in Access), they return fine. It's not the same query that locks up each time either. I thought that it might be something specific to our software that I hadn't managed to track down until I found a very similar post here (unfortunately with no reply except mine!) 
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?653166-Using-Dao-3.6-on-Windows-server-2008&highlight=dao+3.6+server+2008

The only thing I have found so far is that the version of DAO360.dll on the server that it runs on is 3.60.9704, and the version on the server with problems is 3.60.9756 (i.e. a newer version of Dao). I did not install or register anything manually, but installed Access 97 and Access 2003 on the new server, the same as the old server. I should also point out that If i move the back end code as-is to the old server, then the tests work fine, so I'm pretty sure it is not the code.

Now I know that DAO is outdated and all that, but I'm stuck with this codebase until the migrated solution is available and thoroughly tested, so any thoughts of where to look would be very welcome indeed. In the meantime, I'm going to try and manually register the 3.60.9704 version on the new server and run more tests to see if that is the issue, but it would be kind of weird if it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha ! Although we are only using DAO, not full blown access, this seems to be the answer

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officesetupdeployprevious/thread/2a34fc07-0a1e-4248-b866-2b1c60aabba2

When I looked a bit more into it, the server that the code is running on fine is Windows 2008 webserver, which, although it is 64 bit, is a completely different beast to the OS on the new machine which is Windows Server 2008 R2. Solution seems to be to go back to an older OS on the server, rather than re-writing the whole app, which is an easy thing to do for us.
Luckily, this only has to run for another few months or so, as the whole thing is being re-written.